# Composer require local package

Tags: php, composer-php

I've got a couple of libraries [Foo and Bar] that I'm developing in concert, but are still technically separate things. Previously I've just re-defined the autoloader to like `"Foo\\": "../Foo/src"`, but now that I've added a Guzzle dependency to Foo, Bar flips it's lid because it's not one of its dependencies.

Directory structure:

```
/home/user/src/
    Foo/
        src/
            FooClient.php
        composer.json
    Bar/
        src/
            BarClient.php
        composer.json
```

Theoretical Autoload Statement: [in Bar/composer.json]

```
"require": {
    "local": "../Foo/composer.json"
}
```

Example code:

```
require('vendor/autoload.php');

$f = new \Bar\BarClient(new \Foo\FooClient());
```

How can I resolve this without setting up a local Composer repo? I want to maintain these as separate packages, just that one requires the other, and therefor processes the other's dependencies.

#### post-answer edit:

Thanks to infomaniac I've done the following:

Initialized the git repo:

```
cd ~/src/Foo && git init && echo -e "vendor\ncomposer.lock" > .gitignore && git add ./ && git commit -m "Initial Commit"
```

Added the composer config:

```
"require": {
    "sammitch/foo": "dev-master"
},
"repositories": [{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "/home/sammitch/src/Foo"
}],
```

And then `composer update`!

Comment: How does this json specify the identity between the reference to "sammitch/foo" and the address of "/home/sammitch/src/Foo" ?
Is it following any convention?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli `sammitch/foo` is the package name and has literally nothing to do with where it is located. Will construct a list of available packages based on its configured repos, in this case fetching the composer.json from the specified local git repo, and then composer handles the rest. The `sammitch/foo` package is copied to the current app's `vendor` folder the same as any other package.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it now.  It's just a custom repo, like in APT, that might happen to contain the "sammit/foo" package.  Did I get it right?

Comment: @SebastiánGrignoli you betcha

Comment: thanks for saying "flips it's lid"...made me laugh :D

Comment: i guess the term "Theoretical" is not a good choice here, use "Hypothetical" instead :D

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use Composer's *repositories* feature

https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

```
{
  "repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "../../packages/my-package"
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "my/package": "*"
  }
}
```

Instead of using the http format, specify a file path on disk.

Comment: http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/22929686367/composer-installing-package-from-local-git

Comment: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path is also potentially useful and seemed to work better for me.

Comment: @JasmineHegman indeed! I've used that too - great for development

Comment: To make this a good answer, you should show HOW to do it, and not just name the feature and link the docs (although that is also important). Other answers below have proper examples.

Comment: For me, as of 2022, `@dev` worked rather than `*` for the package version.

Answer (score 298):

The way to link to a local, in-development package is to first add in your main project's `composer.json` a **repository**, like this:

```json
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "/full/or/relative/path/to/development/package"
    }
]
```

You also need to either have a version specified in your development package's `composer.json` or the way I do it is to require the package using `@dev`, like this:

```bash
composer require "vendorname/packagename @dev"
```

It should output:

```
- Installing vendor/packagename (dev-develop)
Symlinked from /full/or/relative/path/to/development/package
```

The `@dev` in the require command is important, composer uses this to pickup the source code and symlink it to your new package.

It's a stability flag added to the version constraint (see [package link](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#package-links)).

> These allow you to further restrict or expand the
>   stability of a package beyond the scope of the [minimum-stability](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability)
>   setting.

The minimum-stability flags are:

> Available options (in order of stability) are `dev`, `alpha`, `beta`, `RC`, and `stable`.

Comment: Note, that you are not allowed by composer to specify a path that is in the same directory the composer.json is placed.

Comment: Interesting point, MaPePeR I did not know this. However, I guess all the web frameworks already take care of this by putting all the dependencies into a "vendor" folder? Yii2 does this, at least.

Comment: I think i confused this with something else. It is not allowed to have a repository in a parent folder. A child folder should be fine, but it caused some weird errors for me.

Comment: `composer require "vendorname/packagename @dev"`
translates to
`"require":{
        "vendorname/packagename": "@dev"
    }`
in your app's composer.json if you want to run composer install

Comment: Please, add this: composer config repositories.local path /full/or/relative/path/to/development/package as correct way of adding repositories

Comment: I followed these instructions but I get an error that `autoload.php` can't be found when deploying to an Elastic Beanstalk instance

Comment: @chuck-le-butt try and see what the composer version you're getting on your EB instance, might need updating? Maybe this: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=149579

Comment: Is it possible to tell composer to install it to the vendors folder for prod instead of creating a symlink?

Comment: For anyone that has the package installed, you might need to remove the existing package `composer remove "package-name"` before running these instructions.

Comment: Is this okay to be used in production?

Comment: @LouisSayers Yes, you can force composer to copy instead of symlinking by using:

`"options": {"symlink": false}`

See: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Answer (score 14):

After spending some time, I finally understood the solution. Maybe it'll be useful for someone like me and will save you some time, so I've decided that I have to share it here.

Assuming that you have the following directory structure (relative to your project root directory):

```
composer.json
config
config/composition-root.php
local
local/bar-project
local/bar-project/composer.json
local/bar-project/src
local/bar-project/src/Bar.php
public
public/index.php
src
src/Foo.php
```

In this example you may see that the `local` folder is meant for nested projects of your company, e.g. `bar-project`. But you could configure any other layout, if you wish.

Each project has to have its own `composer.json` file, e.g. root `composer.json` and `local/bar-project/composer.json`. Then their contents would be as follows:

(root `composer.json`:)

```
{
  "name": "your-company/foo-project",
  "require": {
    "php": "^7",
    "your-company/bar-project": "@dev"
  },
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "YourCompany\\FooProject\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "local/bar-project"
    }
  ]
}
```

(`local/bar-project/composer.json`:)

```
{
  "name": "your-company/bar-project",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "YourCompany\\BarProject\\": "src/"
    }
  }
}
```

If, for example, you wish to locate each project in a separate sibling directory, as follows:

```
your-company
your-company/foo-project
your-company/foo-project/composer.json
your-company/foo-project/config
your-company/foo-project/config/composition-root.php
your-company/foo-project/public
your-company/foo-project/public/index.php
your-company/foo-project/src
your-company/foo-project/src/Foo.php
your-company/bar-project
your-company/bar-project/composer.json
your-company/bar-project/src
your-company/bar-project/src/Bar.php
```

- then you need to link to respective directory in `repositories` section:

```
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "path",
      "url": "../bar-project"
    }
  ]
```

After that don't forget to `composer update` (or even `rm -rf vendor && composer update -v` as [the docs suggest](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md))!
Under the hood, composer will create a `vendor/your-company/bar-project` symlink that targets to `local/bar-project` (or `../bar-project` respectively).

Assuming that your `public/index.php` is just a `front controller`, e.g.:

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__ . '/../config/composition-root.php';
```

Then your `config/composition-root.php` would be:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use YourCompany\BarProject\Bar;
use YourCompany\FooProject\Foo;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$bar = new Bar();
$foo = new Foo($bar);
$foo->greet();
```

Comment: "rm -rf vendor/company/package" is important

Comment: @Alex83690 only if you have already run `composer update` with similar `composer.json` and therefore you need to remove the previous symlink created by composer

Answer (score 3):

The command line way to do this is

```
composer config repositories.package_name local path/to/package
composer require group/package_name
```

If the group/package_name is available both from repository and local, the local version is used.

The `local` command can be replaced with vcs to reference a direct repository, or `composer` for default.

Comment: So you can not have project that use repository for a package while other are using local, nope ?