# Install package with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I want to install a package with the composer. I input the next command:

```
composer global require package-name
```

installed a package with package-name from packagist.org, but I want to install a local package with the same name.

Please, prompt me, how I can explain the composer, that it must install a local package?

Comment: Possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994088/composer-require-local-package

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Composer require local package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29994088/composer-require-local-package)