# How to test composer package in developpement, like for symfony packages

Tags: symfony, open-source

i am wondering how the contributions on framework like symfony or laravel works.

For example if i clone the [symfony repository](https://github.com/symfony/symfony) i'll have the src folder that create the package. And when this package is used there is other folder like in the symfony skeleton.

So how is it possible to develop and test the code without publishing the package ?

Comment: Please share more details. All components contain a test directory, and there is a `phpunit.xml.dist` in the root folder. What else is missing from your point of view?

Comment: i meant when you are making changes on a project like symfony, how you run your code and test it manualy without publishing it to pakagist

Comment: You check the code out and run your test suite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write tests for the package code and also install the package from your local directory to kind of do the integration testing. Also you can run `composer require symfony/package:dev-master#<commit hash>` to install specific commit package version.

This is answer would be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995226/4620016

Comment: So if i understand it right, it would be possible to have a project that is like the symfony skeleton where you change the package sources by the path of the source symfony package ?

Comment: Yes, you can have a local project with dev versions of dependencies and special test cases for them. Also you can use `composer require symfony/symfony:dev-master#<commit>` to install package with specific commit version.