# How merge package composer.json file?

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php

I create my own package located in the root folder named `/ECommerce`.

This directory contains `composer.json` and my package code.

When I want to add a new package to `ECommerce/composer.json`, which is necessary for the package to work, after calling the `$ composer update/install` command, that package is not installed.

If I add the desired package to the root `composer.json` it is installed.

Is there any possibility to merge these two composer.json files or do I have to copy `composer.json` from the root folder to the package folder at the end of the project

Example:

```
Structure: /
       - app
       - Ecommerce
         - ...
         - composer.json
       - resources
       - vendor
       - composer.json
       - ....
```

I add `composer require nwidart/laravel-modules` in Ecommerce and that is not installed.

If I add in root `composer.json`, then it becomes installed.

Comment: Did you require your Ecommerce package in the root composer.json ? if not you could look at that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995226/8126784

Comment: Only in `autoload PSR-4`

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want to accomplish. Why do you have a package in a separate directory, with its own  `composer.json` file? Why don't you install this package with composer, and declare it in the project's composer.json file?

Comment: Ivan, have you seen my answer below, and my comment above? Any feedback at all?

Answer (score 0):

Simply, composer does not support multiple, nested or otherwise, `composer.json` files, aside from the ones that come from the managed dependencies.

There is a single `composer.json` per project, declaring that project's dependencies.

Then each project has their own `composer.json` file to declare **their** dependencies, and the whole thing is resolved when executing `update`, `install`, `require`, etc.

Having a package installed manually in a separate directory, when that project has more Composer dependencies, is a Bad Idea. If that package is actually a composer package and declare its own dependencies, then install it as a project package (`require your/package`), and let Composer deal with dependencies when appropriate. If you add/change/remove dependencies in `your/package`, then you `composer update` the root project, and you let Composer install/change whatever else is needed.

Note: there is a 3rd party plugin that appears to support merging multiple `composer.json` files.

https://github.com/wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin

Haven't used it myself; and while there is might be the occasional use for such structure, it's not a built-in capability, and more often than not you'd be better off doing things the "usual" way.