Laravel 11, Facing error in Provider is not found in Module
Class "Modules\AdminModule\Providers\AdminModuleServiceProvider" not found is an error I'm encountering when I create a module in Laravel called AdminModule.
When I attempted to utilize the composer dump auto-load command, I also encountered issues like

Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1


"merge-plugin": {
    "include": [
        "Modules/*/composer.json"
    ]
}

Manually need to add the above code in composer.json file. After we run the command composer dump-autoload

This is not exactly the right solution, you should not have this issue at all... you are missing adding the package loading to your project. This is exactly what you want and is the correct answer, not what you did: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29995226/1998801

The error you're encountering mostly occurs when Laravel cannot find the class or file for your module's service provider due to one of the following issues:

Namespace misalignment
Make sure the namespace in your AdminModuleServiceProvider matches the
directory structure and the module's PSR-4 autoload configuration in composer.json.

namespace Modules\AdminModule\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AdminModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider

{
    
public function register()
    {
        // Register services
    }

    public function boot()
    {
        // Bootstrap services
    }
}


If your file is located at Modules/AdminModule/Providers/AdminModuleServiceProvider.php, the namespace must match Modules\AdminModule\Providers.
Composer AutoLoading
If you created the module manually, ensure your composer.json file includes the module's namespace in the autoload section:

    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Modules\\AdminModule\\": "Modules/AdminModule/"
        }
    }


After editing composer.json, run:

    composer dump-autoload


Module Discovery


Verify that the module is registered in the Laravel application's config/app.php (if applicable) or modules_statuses.json file:

    {
        "Modules\\AdminModule\\": true
    }


Fixing the package:discover Issue


Run composer dump-autoload again, ensuring no syntax or path errors exist in the project.
If the issue persists:

Check composer.json for post-autoload scripts that might be failing:
 "scripts": {
"post-autoload-dump": [
    "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
  ]
}




Manually run the failing command to see the specific error:

    php artisan package:discover


Clearing Laravel Caches


Laravel may cache the service provider or autoloaded files. Clear the caches to refresh:

    php artisan config:clear
    
    php artisan cache:clear
    
    php artisan route:clear
    
    php artisan clear-compiled
    
    php artisan optimize

Debugging Steps

Verify the file path for AdminModuleServiceProvider.php.
Ensure the class name and namespace are correctly defined.
Check the autoload configuration in composer.json.
Run the following commands sequentially:

    composer dump-autoload
    
    php artisan package:discover
    
    php artisan config:clear



Thanks for your comments. I miss the code in composer. json
